# Windows Phone 8.1 RT Application Insights

Tags: visual-studio, azure, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, azure-application-insights

I developed a Windows phone 8.1 RT app (NOT Silverlight)

I want to upload it to the Windows Phone store and add "Application Insights Telemetry" to it.

According to [the Visual Studio ALM blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/09/17/application-insights-tools-in-visual-studio-2013-summer-update.aspx) 8.1 is not supported in telemetry, so I am forced to use the new Azure Telemetry (the new version of this tool which uses Azure instead of Visual Studio Online).  Thing is, I registered for a trial in Azure and the Application Insights feature is "coming soon"....

How can I make it track the crashes, errors, and data usage of my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that [`https://mint.splunk.com/`](https://mint.splunk.com/) was a good tool for monitoring 8.1 apps for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Windows phone support was added in January.

Docs: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-windows-get-started/

Blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/01/07/application-insights-now-supports-windows-phone-and-windows-store-applications.aspx